# Triggering change event when changing value of a input tag by button click jquery

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#button1").click(event => {
    let body = `
    <button id="button2">Button2</button><input type="text" id="inputbox" value="xyz">
    `;
    $("#wrapper").html(body);
  });
  $("#wrapper").on("click", "#button2", (event) => {
    $(event.target).siblings("#inputbox").val("Changed Value") .trigger("change");
  });
  $("#wrapper").on("change", "#inputbox", (event) => {
    console.log("Value Changed");
    console.log(event.target);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="button1">Button 1</button>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I click button1 an input box and button2 is created.When I change the value in input box manually change event is triggered but when I do it by clicking button2 change event is not triggered.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use : `..val("Changed Value").trigger("change")`